# How to set up a windows cython environment from scratch?

Tags: cython, development-environment

I have been searching on the internet for hours to find out how to make cython work with no success.

I am on windows , i use python3 with Anaconda and i also have Codeblocks using the mingw GCC compiler.

I would like to be able to run even the most basic code (like 'helloworld') with cython because untill now i've only encountered errors i don't understand. They may come from an unstable developping environment so this is why i ask this question.

The main errors happen when translating the .pyx code to .c and even when i achieve that there are even more errors on the .c generated.

---

here is my 'helloworld.pyx' :

```py
print('Hello Wolrd')
```

here is my setup.py :

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules=cythonize('helloworld.pyx'))
```

when i run `python3 setup.py` i get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'`

when i run `cython helloworld.pyx` , I get a file `helloworld.c`
but when i run it in Codeblocks i get the error `Python.h : no such file or directory`

so i temporary fixed it by puting the absolute path in the include command but i still get errors.

---

i also tried using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` but i get

```
running build_ext
building 'helloworld' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -IC:\Users\Julien\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\Julien\anaconda3\include -c helloworld.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\helloworld.o
In file included from C:\Users\Julien\anaconda3\include/Python.h:87:0,
                 from helloworld.c:4:
C:\Users\Julien\anaconda3\include/pytime.h:123:59: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list
C:\Users\Julien\anaconda3\include/pytime.h:123:59: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
C:\Users\Julien\anaconda3\include/pytime.h:131:5: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list
C:\Users\Julien\anaconda3\include/pytime.h:136:5: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list
helloworld.c:201:41: warning: division by zero
helloworld.c:201:12: error: enumerator value for '__pyx_check_sizeof_voidp' is not an integer constant
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

---

I followed tutorials to install mingw (it works for coding in C in codeblocks so I should have installed it properly) and I verified that Cython was correctly installed in Python libraries. What did I do wrong ??

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers. You're much much much better off using MSVC. It also looks like you may have Cython installed in a different conda environment than the one you're using to run setup.py.

Comment: This solved my problem. I reinstalled properly using the explanations on the webpage you gave me and with a little bit more work it runs fine now. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was effectively in the compilers.

the problem was because my mingw compiler was not correct : i suggest following
[these instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO2Fd.png) which you will find at https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers.

/!\ do not forget to install setuptools on your python environment (using the command given works for me)

this should at least allow you to make the [basic tutorial](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) for cython